# What’s the recommended way of mounting with rclone in on Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: mount, desktop-environments, fstab, automount, rclone

I want to configure an encrypted rclone mount on a Linux desktop system for a backup solution (probably [PikaBackup](https://apps.gnome.org/de/app/org.gnome.World.PikaBackup/) installed via [Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.gnome.World.PikaBackup)) that stores on a cloud storage.

The storage *could* be mounted on demand (i.e. when PikaBackup tries to access it) or all the time. But it should be user writeable and available without any manual process when the backup process runs.

Therefore I'm curious what kind of mount variant is suggested in that case.
And what are advantages or disadvantages of different mounting types.

Nowadays there are possibilities to use `fstab` entries now and other users are using `automount`, `systemd` or [this wrapper script](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/wiki/rclone-mount-helper-script). Maybe there's even a solution of having it visible via gvfs or so?

**PS:** It should automatically reconnect if necessary (i.e. when there were some connection issues, a reconnect or the notebook woke up from suspend) therefore the mounting/unmounting process shouldn't involve any manual intervention or lead to data loss.

Comment: I use a simple one liner in cron KISS! `@reboot rclone mount --allow-other GDrive: ~/GDrive/`